# How to play IBM Watson Text To Speech audio on localhost using Node.js

Tags: node.js, audio, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I'm building a Web Application that receive an input from a user, pass it to the IBM Watson Text To Speech API and then play the result. The only page from the application consist of a list of input with a 'Listen' button next to it. When the button is clicked, I get the related text from the database and add it in the payload for the API.

I am able to get the result from the api, that is written on a .mp3 file but at the time that the audio should be played, I get two types of problems:

1. First time that the button is clicked, the file is created but the audio is not played. If I press the **same** button once again, it plays the audio;
2. Second problem is when I choose a diferente text, I get the following error:

> 

```
    internal/buffer.js:72
  throw new ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE(type || 'offset',
  ^

RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "offset" is out of range. It must be >= 0 and <= 15922. Received -1282654053
    at boundsError (internal/buffer.js:72:9)
    at Buffer.readInt32LE (internal/buffer.js:376:5)
    at TextToSpeechV1._this.repairWavHeader (C:\Users\Pedro\Documents\udemy\projetoNode\node_modules\ibm-watson\text-to-speech\v1.js:82:45)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Pedro\Documents\udemy\projetoNode\node_modules\ibm-watson\text-to-speech\v1.js:45:35)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:228:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
  code: 'ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE'
```

Here's part of the code responsible for calling the IBM TTS API and play the audio:

```
            // result from the mysql's query
            let comment = results[0].comentario;
            console.log("Comment: " + comment);

            //text_to_speech api
            let payload = {
                text: comment,
                accept: 'audio/mp3',
                voice: 'pt-BR_IsabelaV3Voice'
            }

            textToSpeech.synthesize(payload)
                .then(response => {
                    return textToSpeech.repairWavHeaderStream(response.result);
                })
                    .then(buffer => {
                        fs.writeFileSync('audio.mp3', buffer);
                        console.log('audio ok');
                    })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('error:', err);
                });

            const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'audio.mp3')
            sound.play(filePath);
```

I'm using Express and [Sound-Play](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sound-play) to play the audio file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are falling foul of Node.js async behaviour. Which means that you attempt to play the audio before you have received it. In fact you attempt to play the audio even if an error is thrown. On a subsequent play you will be playing the previously downloaded audio file. <s>Your buffer error is more than likely related to the same problem.</s>

You are responding to the promise of the `synthesize` method, so you could wrap your own code into a promise, and only attempt to play the audio on resolution of the promise. If you want to keep the same flow that you have then:

```js
  textToSpeech.synthesize(payload)
    .then(response => {
      return textToSpeech.repairWavHeaderStream(response.result);
    })
    .then(buffer => {
      fs.writeFileSync('audio.mp3', buffer);
      console.log('audio ok');
      return Promise.resolve();
    })
    .then(() => {
      const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'audio.mp3');
      sound.play(filePath);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('error:', err);
             
    });
```

After the discussion in the comments, it is clear that your buffer error is because you are attempting to invoke `repairWavHeaderStream` on a .mp3 file. You don't need this step, and your code flow should be:

```js
  textToSpeech.synthesize(payload)
    .then(response => {
      fs.writeFileSync('audio.mp3', response.result);
      console.log('audio ok');
      return Promise.resolve();
    })
    .then(() => {
      const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'audio.mp3');
      sound.play(filePath);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('error:', err);
             
    });
```

Although you should ideally add in a step that checks that response.result is actually a buffer, before you actually try to write it to file.

You should be consistent with your use of `;` either use them or don't!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That worked great for problem 1 but the number 2 is still happening.

Comment: The fact that all this synthesize is wrapped inside of a connection.query() could be the problem?

Comment: Which line in your code does the error stack point at?

Comment: That indicates that the response from `textToSpeech.synthesize(payload)` is not audio. Most likely it’s an error message. Try logging the response to see what it contains.

Comment: The response from it is pretty huge. Is there any field on the response that I should pay attention to it?

Comment: Check the status code, if its not 200 then there will be an error message. That said, if you are seeing a large amount of binary data when you synthesise your 'different text' then it could be that you are not requesting a wav file. Default is `audio/ogg;codecs=opus`

Comment: Well, I change my accept to audio/wav and now it seems to be working perfectly. What do you think that could be the cause of the buffer's problem with .mp3?

Comment: You were most likely calling `repairWavHeaderStream` on a non .wav file, you should only call it on .wav files.

Comment: Couold you edit your answer adding what we just talked about .wav so I can Accept your answer entirely?